# Finding the kinetic energy of a cylinder swinging inside another cylinder

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics

I'd like to solve the following problem:

> An homogeneous cylinder of mass $m$, radius $a$ and height $h$ rolls without slipping inside a cylindrical surface of radius $R > a$. Find the kinetic energy and the frequency for small oscillations.

[image: Figure 1[1]]

I tried solving it by considering the kinetic energy associated with the translation of the center of mass of the smaller cylinder plus the kinetic energy of the rotation around the contact line between the cylinders and, finally, the rotation around the axis that passes through the center of the bigger cylinder:

$$
T = \frac{1}{2}mV_{CM}^2 + \frac{1}{2}I_1\omega^2 + \frac{1}{2}I_2\dot{\theta}^2
$$
where $V_{CM}$ is the velocity of the center of mass; $I_1$ is the moment of inertia around the axis that passes through the contact line between the cylinders; $I_2$ is the moment of inertia around the axis that passes through the center of the bigger cylinder and $\dot{\theta}$ is the angular velocity of the rotation of the CM of the smaller one around the center axis that passes through the center of the cylinder with radius $R$. At the end, I had:

$$
T = \frac{9}{4}m\dot{\theta}^2(R-a)^2 + \frac{1}{2}ma^2\dot{\theta}^2
$$

Apparently, my professor does not consider the first one, only the translation of cylinder with radius $a$ and the swinging around the axis through the cylinder of radius $R$, and I can't figure out why. He got this:

$$
T = \frac{1}{2}mV_{CM}^2 + \frac{1}{2}I_1\omega^2
$$
$$
T = \frac{3}{4}m(R-a)^2\dot{\theta}^2
$$

Comment: Don't think that the equation that you wrote down for the kinetic energy is correct. It has been shown that the total kinetic energy of an object is the sum of its translational kinetic energy plus its rotational kinetic energy about its center-of-mass, but I'm not aware of any justification for breaking down the total kinetic energy into the sum of the three terms shown in your first equation for T.

Comment: I think you should use this equation $R\omega =a\dfrac{d\theta }{dt}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem with your equation for energy is that the term $\frac12 m V_{CM}^2$ is already included in the term $\frac12 I_1\omega^2$ for the energy of rotation about the point of contact with the large cylinder.

To understand why this is true analyse the circular motion of a point mass about a fixed point with constant speed. For its kinetic energy we consider only $\frac12mv^2$. But if we take this term and also $\frac12 I \omega^2$
we would get double of the actual kinetic energy.